# Proving a linear map is surjective - is my proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $T: K^n \rightarrow K^{n-1}$ be a linear map such that $\text{ker}(T) = \{(a,0,0) : a \in K \}$. Prove that $T$ is surjective.

My proof:

using rank-nullity theorem, we have $\dim(K^n) = \text{rank} T + \text{nullity} T \Rightarrow n = \text{rank} T + 1 \Rightarrow \text{rank} T = n-1$.

So the basis of the image of $T$ contains $n-1$ linearly independent vectors. So it must span $K^{n-1}$, i.e. $T$ maps onto $K^{n-1}$, so it is surjective.

Is it correct? Any improvements I can make to make the proof more "rigorous"/concise etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. I'm not sure how clear you are supposed to be so I would add that the $n-1$ linearly independent vectors are in $K^{n-1}$ so therefore span $K^{n-1}$.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much :)